# the redirect from http to https does not work in nginx

Tags: nginx

I am trying to redirect all the *http* traffic to *https* and my nginx conf looks like this:

```
     upstream upstreamServer {

         server upstream_serv:80;

     }




     server {

         listen 80;

         server_name ~^(([a-zA-Z0-9]+)|)test\.xy\.abc\.io$ ;


         access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  backend; 

         location / {

             return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

         }

     }

     server {

         listen                   443 ssl;

         server_name ~^(([a-zA-Z0-9]+)|)test\.xy\.abc\.io$ ;



         ssl_protocols            TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;

         ssl_certificate          /path/to/cert_chain.pem;

         ssl_certificate_key      /path/to/cert_key.pem;

         ssl_trusted_certificate  /path/to/cert_chain.pem;



         access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  backend; 


         # Redirect all traffic in /.well-known/ to lets encrypt
             location  /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
                 root   /var/tmp;
                 index  index.html index.htm;
             }

         location / {

             proxy_pass http://upstreamServer;

             proxy_set_header Host $host;

             proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;

             proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;

             proxy_buffering off;

             if ($uri ~* ".(js|png|jpg|jpeg|svg|gif|avi|mp3|mp4)$" ){

                 expires 1d;

                 add_header Cache-Control public;

             }

             proxy_pass_request_headers on;

         }

     }
```

But for some reason it doesn't work. I read about how the nginx chooses the server block and location block. The setup looks correct to me according to what I understand but still the site keeps loading on http when I hit the url `http://test.xy.abc.io` instead of redirecting me to https.

I also tried using only

```
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
```

instead of

```
            location / {

                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

            }
```

but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Did I get right that your page is still loading the unencrypted http version? Did you reaload the service to load the changed config file? (sorry to ask that stupid question back)

```
nginx -t && nginx -s reload
```

I personally use in all nginx instances I maintain something like this:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  # no server_name means all

  # For let's encrypt domains: .well-known/acme-challenge
  location '/.well-known/acme-challenge' {
    default_type "text/plain";
    root /var/www/certbot;
  }

  # Redirect http -> https.
  location / {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri$is_args$args;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, the page is still loading the unencrypted http version.
Yes, I did reload the service.
I have tried the default_server as well and that doesn't work either.

Comment: Can you please switch the error log to info mode and let me know what it logs (all lines) when you access the page?

Comment: Thanks for your reply jj. I found the reason why it was happening. Posting the answer.

Comment: Cool thanks for letting me know. Was just testing in my lab environment and so I can save some time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was there is a GCP loadbalancer before my nginx proxy. Which was forwarding all the requests on *https* to my nginx proxy no matter if the orignal reuquest was *http* or *https*. After searching the internet I found that loadbalancer can not force https on clients. So this what I had to do in my nginx location block.

```
if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = http) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

and the complete solution looks like this:

```
     server {
         listen 80;
         listen 443 ssl;

         server_name ~^(([a-zA-Z0-9]+)|)test\.xy\.abc\.io$ ;



         ssl_protocols            TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;

         ssl_certificate          /path/to/cert_chain.pem;

         ssl_certificate_key      /path/to/cert_key.pem;

         ssl_trusted_certificate  /path/to/cert_chain.pem;



         access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  backend; 


         # Redirect all traffic in /.well-known/ to lets encrypt
             location  /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
                 root   /var/tmp;
                 index  index.html index.htm;
             }

         location / {
             if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = http) {
                 return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
             }

             proxy_pass http://upstreamServer;

             proxy_set_header Host $host;

             proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;

             proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;

             proxy_buffering off;

             if ($uri ~* ".(js|png|jpg|jpeg|svg|gif|avi|mp3|mp4)$" ){

                 expires 1d;

                 add_header Cache-Control public;

             }

             proxy_pass_request_headers on;

         }

     }
```